# Render haml with locals and partials within partials to html file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, render

I need to create some html files and want to use my partials already done to the show view. 
I used to do this with markaby, but now i think that with haml the thing will be easier. 
I'm trying to do:

```
Haml::Engine.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/metric_box_sets/_metric_box_set.html.haml"), 
:format => :html5, :ugly => true).render(Object.new,locals =>{:metric_box_set=>@metric_box_set})
```

in the partial that i'm using, i access metric_box_set several times, but also render other partials and give them other objects that are associated with this one. The problem is it's giving an error on the render method. There is some way to tell it that the render method it should use is the normal render method?

Tnks!

Comment: Where are you using this code? Where are you setting `@metric_box_set`?

Comment: Is it a typo or a bug that you have `Object.new, locals ={:metric...}` instead of `Object.new, locals => {:metric...}` (notice the `>` to properly finish off the hash rocket)?

Comment: now i'm just testing it in the console, i want to create a worker to generate this html files to improve the server response, but that variable is an active record object, i set it before execute this line.

Comment: @nzifnab it was bug... when i adjusted the code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found other solution to do this.
Instead of using Haml::Engine, once we are already in rails and we can use render itself, i created a to_html function in the model and include the application helper to get the helper_methods that i used in the partial. Then used the render to print the result to a file:

```
def to_html
  ActionView::Base.send :include, ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper

  File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "public", 'test.html'), "w") do |file|

    file.print ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"].first).render(
                :partial => 'metric_box_sets/metric_box_set', 
                :format => :html,
                :locals => { :metric_box_set => self}
              )
  end  
end
```

This way i can generate all html snippets that i needed based on the views that i already done.

Answer (score -1):

You've got a typo - `locals =>` should be `locals =`